# Can't install maven

Tags: java, windows, jakarta-ee, maven

I set up all my environment variable correctly but I'm getting a weird error, there is no match on google for the class name (which is just giberish)

So I added the 2 required environment variable :

```
JAVA_HOME   C:\programs\Java\jdk1.6.0_41
M2_HOME     C:\dev\apache-maven-3.0.4

And added this at the end of the variable PATH
;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin
```

And when running mvn --version I get :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ûXX
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ûXX
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: ÔÇôXX.  Program will exit.
```

The weird thing is that I get exactly the same thing on 2 totally different computers.
I tried with old file that I already had and freshly downloaded files.

I don't get it.

Comment: You download maven from oficial site?

Comment: Try adding the options for printing errors (-e) and verbose output (-X).

Comment: Yes it was taken from the apache website and the JDK from it's website too.
Adding -e or -X generate the same thing.

Comment: Sounds like a broken installation of JDK and/or Maven.

Comment: Which would have happened on 2 different computer with with 2 installation (for the JDK). that would be a hell of a coincidence.

Comment: I should precise that maven is working inside eclipse with M2E (right clic>run as> maven install) and is building correctly.
But I need to be able to use the command line because I'm going to work on a project without M2E

Comment: What do you get when calling `java -version`? Maybe there is another Java on the path.

Comment: java version "1.6.0_41"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_41-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Which Windows version, and are you running regular shell?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bits, I'm running the standard shell and I'm using the JDK 32 Bits

Comment: Is Eclipse set up to use the installed version (C:\dev\apache-maven-3.0.4) or it's embedded version? See Prefs:Maven:Installations.

Comment: The external one (C:\dev\apache-maven-3.0.4), the embedded usually generate a lot of errors

Comment: This looks like some problems with encoding.

Comment: Are you launching the mvn executable that you expect - the one in M2_HOME/bin? (i.e. are there any matches on "mvn" other places earlier in your PATH?)

Comment: yes, c:\dev\apache-maven-3.0.1\bin\mvn.bat --version in cmd produce the same result

Comment: Did you download the binary or source? If you downloaded a source archive, download a binary archive and re-install. 
You could also try selecting a different mirror.
If all else fails install a Linux distribution and run `sudo apt-get install maven` from a terminal ;)

Comment: I tried on a third computer, doing excatly the same thing with the same files, and it is working correctly on the third.
It must be coming from the windows installation, still can't figure out why tho.

Comment: re:yes, c:\dev\apache-maven-3.0.1\bin\mvn.bat --version in cmd produce the same result ---- but in the question you set the env to C:\dev\apache-maven-3.0.4

Comment: Yeah, disregard that, I tried several maven version since I posted here, that's why, the environment variable point to the right path (otherwhise I wouldn't get anything when typing mvn --version)

Comment: excute the command "java -version" and show us the result

Comment: java version "1.6.0_41" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_41-b02) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode, sharing) (same result on the computer where it's not working and the one where it's working)

Comment: Assuming this is Windows, remember that there can be a "system" Java runtime executable in the PATH before your JAVA_HOME\bin. Make sure you are running the Java you think you are.

Answer (score 1):

This works on my PC with Win7 64x OS:

```
JAVA_HOME  c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_21
J2_HOME    c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin
M2_HOME    c:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.1.0
PATH       ...;%M2_HOME%\bin;%J2_HOME%
```

Sometimes, when we want get PATH without spaces, we can use this trick:

```
'Progra~1' instead of 'Program Files'
'Progra~2' instead of 'Program Files (x86)'
 and etc
```

This is old DOS filenames style: 8+3 - where 8 chars for name and 3 for extension (if it present)

This works on old Win machines

Answer (score 0):

when passing maven path try to come in to maven package and get path, I had a maven package inside of maven package,so my path is C:\apache-maven-3.6.0\apache-maven-3.6.0. it is work on my computer.